# Proper formatting in aws ec2 descibe-instance

Tags: linux, command-line, amazon-web-services

I am trying to get the details of the ec2-instances using AWS CLI. I am using the command mentioned below:-

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=vpc-id,Values=vpc-6205a31b --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[PrivateIpAddress,PublicIpAddress,State.Name,InstanceId,InstanceType,Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[],Tags[?Key==`Environment`].Value[]]' --output text | column -t
```

But the output format is not consistent as i want.

```
1.1.1.1      None            running   i-0506dddde481d  t2.large
abc-sandbox-dp
sandbox
2.2.2.2       None            running   i-0fea4xx8e1c2x  t2.xlarge
xyz-workshop-dp
workshop
```

instead i want the output in below format

```
1.1.1.1  None   running   i-0506dddde481d t2.large  abc-sandbox-dp sandbox
2.2.2.2  None   running   i-0fea4xx8e1c2x t2.xlarge xyz-workshop-dp workshop
```

Any way to format it , i tried different variations of sed but it did not work.

Comment: How do you want it to be formatted? Can you put an example of format you want?

Comment: Its mentioned below the line where i have written : instead i want the output in below format. to be more precise all the columns should be tab separated.